# I can't select the value in Jcombo box

Tags: java, swing

I am currently doing a project on ordering system. I have problem with getting the values of the Jcombo Box. 
Here's the code for Jcombo Box:

```
JComboBox cb_tableno = new JComboBox();
cb_tableno.setBounds(424, 250, 93, 20);
 cb_tableno.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{ "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"}));
 add(cb_tableno);
```

private void actionPerformedOrder() {
  //retrieve user input

```
    String tableNo= (String)cb_tableno.getSelectedItem();
   Date orderDate = new Date();
   orders = new Orders(Integer.parseInt(tableNo),orderDate, totalAmount);
   int orderID = OrdersDA.createOrders(orders);

    }
```

There is a Jbutton which is called "create" . When i have selected the value in my Jcombo box and press create, there is run time error `String tableNo= (String)cb_tableno.getSelectedItem();`: and  null pointer exception.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the line:

```
JComboBox cb_tableno = new JComboBox();
```

Is hidding the cb_tableno object that you acces in:

```
String tableNo= (String)cb_tableno.getSelectedItem();
```

And that is why the NullPointerException occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information . Do you have any idea how i can slove the problem?

Comment: If the problem is what I said, change the line to `cb_tableno = new JComboBox();`